# Is there a way to change class names in CSS and all instances found in HTML pages link to the CSS?

Tags: html, css

I just finished creating a site with a few HTML pages and a CSS style sheet. Near the end of the project I decided I would like to change some of the class names.

Example:

In my CSS I have `.classname` and in my HTML I have quite a few tags linked to that css class using
`class="classname"`

I would like to change `.classname` to `.class-name` in my CSS Style Sheet, however, if I do this I would have to go through thousands of lines of code in my html pages to find and change all the class names from `class="classname"` to `class="class-name"`

is there a program that can be used that allows you to change a class name in the css and it will go through all html pages and change it there as well?

I use dreamweaver. Is there a way to do this in dreamweaver?

Note: I have tried using the find and replace options in dreamweaver however this does not fully work.

I'm not able to search "`class="classname"`" and replace it with "`class="class-name`" because some tags use "`class="example someclass classname test"`"

I'm not able to search "`classname`" and replace with "`class-name`" because "`classname`" can be found in between `<p></p>` as content and I do not want it to change here.

Thank you!

Comment: You might be able to use JetBrains' [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/)

Comment: Use php: `str_replace('class="classname"', 'class="class-name"', file_get_contents("file.html"));`

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with DreamWeaver options, but if you have a preferred advanced text editor (I use [NPP](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)) you can use [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

I would try an expression such as `(?<=class="[^"]*)(classname)(?=[^"]*")`

And replace that